# apache Mod_rewrite off, wordpress happy, on 404 me unhappy

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress, debian-based

I've been fiddling with the mod_rewrite for some time now, but is has gotten the best of me. Hope anyone here can shine some light on my problem.

I'm trying to self host wordpress and it works great when I set mod_rewrite to off in the .htaccess file for the site. But if I turn it to on it gives me a forbidden error. And log shows:

Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /c/blog/wp-admin/index.php, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

.htaccess contains

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a quirk with hosting wordpress on a readynas where the .htaccess files just make it b0rk. solution is to change from Options Indexes to Options All in /etc/frontview/apache/Shares.conf

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your Apache user (`wwwuser` or `webserv`?) can read `.htaccess` in the root folder.

To make this really easy you can just make the file world-readable and writable (`chmod 777`) but **please be sure** to return it back to a more sane 755 later on.

If you find this is your bug, check the `user:group` on `.htaccess` (`ls -la .htaccess` should do the trick) and make sure that it matches your other files.

Comment: apache runs as: 
NAS:/blog# ps aux | grep apache
admin     5436  0.6  5.2 109812 53464 ?        S    20:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache-ssl -f /etc/frontview/apache/h                                    ttpd.conf
admin     5460  0.0  3.6 106016 37320 ?        S    20:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache-ssl -f /etc/frontview/apache/h                                    ttpd.conf
root      5502  0.0  0.0   3840   500 pts/0    S+   20:35   0:00 grep apache
root     10805  0.0  4.2 104496 43020 ?        Ss   06:25   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache-ssl -f /etc/frontview/apache/h                                    ttpd.conf

Comment: .htaccess has admin:admin as owner

Comment: Did you happen to try combos like apache:admin?, apache:apache apache:root etc?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in your Apache config is forbidding the "RewriteRule" line? The log output suggests you might need to turn on FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch